# Is there any way I can place the TabBar over my header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I had an idea in my design but making it proved harder than I thought. The design is as follows:
[image]

The tabbar here is made with 'createMaterialTopTabNavigator'.
My idea was that the gradient part will be the header so it won't move when navigating from INFO to PHOTOS. I am able the screen the way it looks in the picture above except for the TopTabNavigator overlapping the header. It looks as follows:

[image]

I do understand why this is happening since the topTabNavigator is inside of the stackNavigator and thus the header will always be on top. The thing is that I want the gradient part to stay in place when swiping left or right through the topTabNavigator.

**The profile Stack Screen:**

```
const ProfileStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => { 
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator>
      <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileTabScreen} options={{ 
        header: () => ( <ProfileHeader onPress={() => {navigation.openDrawer()}} />)
      }} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**The header:**

```
const ProfileHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <LinearGradient colors={[color1, color2]}
      start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
      end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
      style={{
        width: '100%,
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingVertical: 50,
     }}>

       <View style={{width: '100%}}>
         <View style={{
           flexDirection: 'row',         
           alignItems: 'center',
           justifyContent: 'space-between',
           paddingHorizontal: 20,
           width: '100%',
       }}>
         <TouchableOpacity><Icon /></TouchableOpacity>

         <TouchableOpacity><Text>Edit profile</Text></TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     </View>
 
     <Image style={{height: 115, width: 115, borderRadius: 100}} source={require('../path/img.jpg')} />
   </LinearGradient>
  );
}
```